# StringBuilder class in java

Tags: java, string, exception

I am trying to learn how to use the StringBuilder class for Exception handling. My current code does not catch an exception because of a blank string. I want it to catch the blank field and display an error message.

```
try {
    String name1 = nameField.getText();  
    String street = streetField.getText();
    String city = cityField.getText();
    String state = stateField.getText();
    String zip = zipField.getText();
    String phone = phoneField.getText();
    String regexStr = "^(1\\-)?[0-9]{3}\\-?[0-9]{3}\\-?[0-9]{4}$";


    nameDisplay.setText("Hello " + name1 + "!");
    streetDisplay.setText(street);
    cityDisplay.setText(city + ", ");
    stateDisplay.setText(state);
    zipDisplay.setText(zip);
    phoneDisplay.setText(phone);
    } 
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter name");
    }
```

Comment: You should never, ever catch NullPointerException. A NullPointerException is a bug. You don't catch the exception. Instead, you fix the bug so that it doesn't happen again. To check if a name if entered in the field, you use `if (nameField.getText()[.trim()].isEmpty())`.

Comment: So what should I list the Exception as?

Comment: Correct. I want to make sure the user enters text into the name field. If it's blank, an error should display. Sorry, i'm new to this.

Comment: Read my amended comment.

Comment: Should control nullity on the fields. Use for that a library like apacheUtils https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html so you can check if a variable is null or empty. Also you can implement your own Exception but avoid to use NullPointerExpception to control that kind of things

Comment: title doesn't make sense

Comment: Just write the `validate` method where you can "ask" if String is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should check variables instead of catching the NPE exception.

```
if (city != null) {
    cityDisplay.setText(city + ", ");
} else {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the name of city");
}
```

and etc...